# Select data from future date

Tags: php, mysql, datediff

I want to show all data which is not updated in 13 days in MYSQL.I tried a lot but i got issue with that..

here is what i tried

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE datediff( curdate( ) , dateupdated )>13
```

I also tried this

```
SELECT * FROM crm_rentals where dateupdated  BETWEEN NOW() AND dateupdated(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
```

I have to do something with:

```
curdate()= dateupdated  +13 days
```

OR

```
dateupdated  = curdate()-13days
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried this?

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE dateUpdated < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 13 DAY
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5a3e/1)